# Populating HTML array variables with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have several text fields carrying the name `first_name[]` in my HTML form. I want to populate those fields with jQuery.

I thought the following would put "Mike" in the first element, then "Samantha" in the second one:

```
jQuery('[name="first_name\\[\\]"]').attr('value', 'Mike');
jQuery('[name="first_name\\[\\]"]').attr('value', 'Samantha');
```

Instead, this code first puts "Mike" in all elements, then puts "Samantha" in all elements". What is the correct manner to achieve that?

Comment: Well, not having the same name attribute would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** here:

```
jQuery('[name="first_name"]:eq(0)').attr('value', 'Mike');
jQuery('[name="first_name"]:eq(1)').attr('value', 'Samantha');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting all elements with that name, so naturally it sets the value for all elements with that name.
To target specific elements, use the [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) (or [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)) functions.

Extra note: instead of using `.attr("value", value)`, use [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

Answer (score 0):

```
var names=['mahi','suni','samantha'];
jQuery('[name="first_name\\[\\]"]').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).val(names[i]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
jQuery('[name*="first_name"]:eq(0)').val('Mike');
jQuery('[name*="first_name"]:eq(1)').val('Samantha');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
var names = ["Mike", "Samantha"];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i+++) {
    jQuery("[name^=first_name]").eq(i).val(names[i]);
}
```

You simply add names to the array to add them to the form.  Obviously, this could be made more robust by adding length checking in so you can't try and add names to form elements that don't exist, but you get the idea.